# boost::posix_time. How to represent both microsecond and nanosecond datetimes in the same application

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to use boost::posix_time::ptime as a 64 bit representation of a datetime with microsecond resolution.
I'd also sometimes like to represent a datetime with nanosecond resolution which uses 96 bits.

Unfortunately, it seems like you have to choose one or the other. Why have the boost developers done this via a #define rather than a template parameter? Is there any way to represent both of these types within the one application?

From: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo

"To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG must be defined in the library users project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc). This macro is not used by the Gregorian system and therefore has no effect when building the library."

Answer (score 0):

The `BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` basically makes the data type use higher precession for the time. Since you need it, use it. I do not see how does,

> "I'd like to use boost::posix_time::ptime as a 64 bit representation of
>   a datetime with microsecond resolution,"

come into that. Are you saying that you are using the `ptime` type as a binary/on-disk representation of the time?

Comment: I don't want to pay for 96 bits when some of my datetimes only require microsecond or millisecond precision. That's the reason the #define exists at all (if 96 bits was no issue, they'd always use nanosecond precision)